# Unable to get the value of variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

EDIT 1: Based on the comments I have changed the code.
EDIT 2: I get what is wrong with the code. What I want to know if how can I make it work?

I want to create a generic function to generate styles as given below.
This is in ES6.

```
const PADDING = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const MARGIN = [0, 8, 16 ];


const generateStyle = (type) => {
  const styles = {};
  const upperCase = type.toUpperCase();

  upperCase.forEach((item) => {
    styles[`${type}-${item}`] = {
      [type]: `${item}px !important`,
    };
  });
  return styles;
};


generateStyle('padding');
```

This code gives the following error: "TypeError: upperCase.forEach is not a function. When I log the uppercase, its value is 'PADDING'.

But when I hardcode PADDING instead of uppercase, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

How to make the function generic so that I can use generateStyle('margin') as well.

Comment: `upperCase` is a string, which doesn't have `forEach` method. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, strings do not have the `forEach` method...? Also, I think `type.` or `String(type).` might be better than `\`${type}\`.`

Comment: I want a way to make the function generic. So that I can call generateStyle('padding') or generateStyle('margin') and get the respective result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const PADDING = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const MARGIN = [0, 8, 16 ];

const generateStyles = (array, type) => {
  if(array && array.length) {
   let styles = {};
    array.forEach(item => {
     styles[`${type}-${item}`] = {
       [type]: `${item}px !important`
      }
    })
    return styles
  }
}

console.log(generateStyles(PADDING, "padding"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

All you need to do is pass an array of values (PADDING) and a css property name ("padding").

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

`` `${type}`.toUpperCase() `` is the string `"PADDING"`, not the variable `PADDING`. You need to put the contents of those variables (`PADDING` and `MARGIN`) in a structure you can use to look them up by name, like an object:

```js
const values = {
  padding: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  margin: [0, 8, 16],
};

const generateStyle = (type) => {
  const styles = {};

  values[type].forEach((item) => {
    styles[`${type}-${item}`] = {
      [type]: `${item}px !important`,
    };
  });
  return styles;
};


console.log(generateStyle('padding'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you don't want to generate a structure, you can also make use of eval and iterate over the variable.

For eg.

```
const PADDING = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const MARGIN = [0, 8, 16 ];


const generateStyle = (type) => {
    const styles = {};
    const upperCase = type.toUpperCase();

    eval(upperCase).forEach((item) => {
        styles[`${type}-${item}`] = {
            [type]: `${item}px !important`,
        };
    });
    return styles;
};


generateStyle('padding');
```

Comment: how's the support for eval in older browsers ?

Comment: I just now checked on IE, firefox and Edge and of course Chrome, it works well. It is not recommended to use it actually as per standard practices, but I believe if you are a careful programmer and not in haste, it should be fine.

**eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller.**

Reference- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 0):

on passing 'padding' to generateStyle, you are just passing a string not the array. so to pass array you need to pass as PADDING only.

Answer (score 0):

Because variable `PADDING` is an array, but when you set the string 'padding' parameter for function `generateStyle` the foreach will iterate over string 'padding', but as I know you can't iterate over string with `Array.forEach()`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `PADDING` is different from the function argument `padding` which is a string.

If you want to evaluate the variable use `eval` which is actually evil

```js
const PADDING = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const MARGIN = [0, 8, 16];


const generateStyle = (type) => {
  const styles = {};
  const upperCase = type.toUpperCase();

  eval(upperCase).forEach((item) => {
    styles[`${type}-${item}`] = {
      [type]: `${item}px !important`,
    };
  });
  return styles;
};


console.log(generateStyle('padding'));
```