# print variables using ${ var } in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

[image]

The above is a screenshot a tutorial in which the tutor used **${ var }** to print a variable in js.

But when i ran the same code, i got like this:
[image]

What is the actual problem?

Comment: you used `'` to format the string, you have to use `(backtick)

Comment: You need to use backtick(`\``) instead of `'`.

Comment: What you are looking for is template literals. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50922888/8349557

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

you must use the backtick [ ` ] ; instead of the using [ ' ],So you can solve it.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong quote type. To do what you want you'll need to use backtick. It's the one to the left of the 1 key on most keyboards.

Answer (score 3):

console.log(`Server at port ${port}`) // Don't put "" or ''. Use ``